Prove that $\{a^nb^m \mid n \leq m\}$ is not regular, using only closure properties
We can use the pumping lemma or the Myhill-Nerode theorem to prove that $\{a^nb^m \mid n \leq m\}$ is not a regular language. It turns out that the proof is kind of similar to the proof for the more famous $\{a^nb^n \mid n \geq 0 \}$. So I wonder: is it possible to prove that $\{a^nb^m \mid n \leq m\}$ is not regular using only closure properties and the fact that $\{a^nb^n \mid n \geq 0 \}$ is not regular? If not, is there a way to prove that closure properties are not powerful enough for this?

Let $L = \{a^nb^m \mid n \leqslant m\}$. Suppose that $L$ is regular. Then so is the reverse language $\tilde L = \{b^ma^n \mid n \leqslant m\}$. Let $h: \{a,b\}^* \to \{a,b\}^*$ be the homomorphism defined by $h(a) = b$ and $h(b) =a$. Since regular languages are closed under homomorphisms, the language $h(\tilde L) = \{a^mb^n \mid n \leqslant m\}$ is regular. But then
$L \cap h(\tilde L) = \{a^nb^n \mid n \geqslant 0\}$ would be regular, a contradiction. Thus $L$ is not regular.

Cool! I hadn't thought about reversing! Alas it sounds like we can use this trick to show $a^nb^m$ is not regular, but can't use it to show $a^nb^nc^m$ is not context free. That one will remain open for now.

You should ask a separate question.
